# autoindent different from manuall indenting

Tags: indentation

We have a custom filetype at work which I use with a plugin i've written.
There we have a construct like this:

```
\item some text.
  it is indented on level more than the \item tag
\item the next item should be indentend the same as the previous one
```

If i type this, I end with that:

```
\item abc
  \item abc
```

Because the indent is increased for the text.
Now if I do a `==` on that line, it is aligned correctly which tells me, that my indent file works correctly. But I want to do this automatically. Since the `\item` tag is used a lot, it is laborious to do it manually all the time.

So my question, what is resposible for the automatic indent, how can my plugin fix that.
I now that it won't be possible to give me an working solutions with the information I provide, but it should be sufficient to point me to the right direction.

Thanks

P.S. I know it looks like LateX, but due to other things used in the fileformat, I can't just use a LateX plugin. (And my Plugin has some other useful stuff).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use the `indentkeys` option, e.g. something like this:

```
setlocal indentkeys+==item
```

For LaTeX files, I use this (in vimtex):

```
setlocal indentkeys+=[,(,{,),},],\&,=item
```

See [`:h indentkeys`](http://vimdoc.sourceforge.net/htmldoc/options.html#'indentkeys') for more info on the syntax.

Comment: And it was this easy... Thank you very much. Unfortunaly I wasn't able to find that information anywhere. However, that was maybe my fault.